# Conditional If statement with regex in awk Unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk

I'm having a problem regarding the if statement with regex inside the awk.
What im trying to do is that, if there is a letter i in the $NF it would print out as Incoming, and if there's a letter o in the $NF value it will display the Outgoing.

Below is the command i'm trying to construct

```
awk -F"/" -v var""'{ if ($NF =~ .*i) then var="Incoming" print $8 ";" $NF ";" var   elif ($NF =~ .*o) print $8 ";" $NF ";" var  }'
```

i always get the error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ( $NF =~ ".*i" ) {print $8 ";" $NF "; Incoming"} else print $8 ";" $NF "; Outgoing" fi }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ( $NF =~ ".*i" ) {print $8 ";" $NF "; Incoming"} else print $8 ";" $NF "; Outgoing" fi }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                       ^ syntax error
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what language that is you're trying to use the syntax of, but it's not awk. Here's how to write what I **think** you are trying to write in awk:

```
awk -F'/' -v OFS=';' '{if ($NF ~ /i/) var="Incoming"; else if ($NF ~ /o/) var="Outgoing"; else var=""; print $8, $NF, var}' file
```

It's also possible that this might be all you need:

```
awk -F'/' -v OFS=';' '{print $8, $NF, ($NF~/i/ ? "Incoming" : "Outgoing")}' file
```

If neither of this is  what you're looking for then edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

You can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.